# Pandas: change column based on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, replace

I am trying to fix my df as it has some wrong values (that are not NA/NAN, just wrong), with the values from another dataframe (`df1`).

I already know which ones are wrong and I got the all sorted in `df1`.

`df` is large, 41 columns and 100000 rows.
`df1` is 5 columns, 5000 rows.

All the data from df1 should be inputed into df. This is done based on a column in both DFs that should match.
`df["SNPS"]` and `df1["ID"]` - I know the names are different, but its essentially the same data.
Then if `ID` matches `SNPS`, I take `df1["VALUES"]` and put its values in `df["OLD_VALUES"]`.

This is what I tried so far in pythons pandas:

```
df = pd.read_table("file_old.txt")
df1 = pd.read_table("file_corrected.txt")

df.loc[df["SNPS"].isin(df1["ID"]), ['OLD_VALUES']] = df1[['VALUES']]
```

This replaces all values that are found but... gives me NaN if the value of the old frame does not exist in the new data frame.
I tried to double the `.isin` thing, but it didnt help:

```
df.loc[df.SNPS.isin(df1.ID), ['OLD_VALUES']] =
  df1.loc[df1.ID.isin(df.SNPS),['VALUES']]
```

This gives me NaN again.

My question is, how can I avoid non-matching `SNPS/ID` column to cause this NaN's? In a way that if the column doesnt match, just skip and leave the old value.

In the output I expect to have DATAFRAME df with all df['OLD_VALUES'] that have the df["SNPS"] same like df1["ID"] replaced by df1["VALUES"] from the new dataframe.

For example:

df is :

```
Chr SNPS OLD_VALUES .....
1 rs123 0.5
2 rs124 0.1
3 rs 125 0.2
```

and df1 is :

```
ID VALUES ...
rs123 0.9
rs125 0.8
```

I want the output of df to look like:

```
Chr SNPS OLD_VALUES .....
1 rs123 0.9
2 rs124 0.1
3 rs 125 0.8
```

So the change was basically with rs123 and rs125 which are in both dataframes, while rs124 is unchanged.

Another edit: problem is SNPS has duplicate values.... which creates an issue with [].values where I cannot broadcast the new series into the old one due to duplications. When I try my code on a smaller dataset it works... But when I try it with duplicates it doesnt.

So this works without duplicate entries:

```
df.loc[df["SNPS"].isin(df1["ID"]), ['OLD_VALUES']] = 
df1.loc[df1.ID.isin(df.SNPS), ['VALUES']].values
```

but with duplicates I get "ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (4,)"

Any way around this?

Comment: Can you add some data samples with expected output?

Comment: hmm, do you check solutions in dupe?

Comment: Yes I did, but its not even similar.
In the dupe they need to change one column, that is also the reference.

In my case my reference is ID, while I need to change column OLD_VALUES.
so I have 2 columns in both files, while the other question has 1 column in file 1 and 2 columns in file 2.

I need to change column OLD_VALUE with VALUE when ID matches SNPS.

Comment: For me solution working nice, for you not? `df['OLD_VALUES'] = df['SNPS'].map(df1.set_index('ID')['VALUES']).fillna(df['OLD_VALUES'])` ?

Comment: Hey!
I actually did a workaround where I merged the tables and then filled NaN of the new column and then swapping columns lol.
Its sticks and ropes but it worked...
But your solution does work! I just had issues understanding how to map with 2 columns.
Thanks a lot